# head commands cause typed key output being gone

Tags: bash, terminal

Why shell tool commands such as head into which data being piped, often make typed key output being invisible, gone on terminal, which will only be fixed by typing `reset <enter>` ?

anyone savvy know a way to prevent it behave so? Please guide

```
$ ls --color -Apv | grep '^[a-z]\w*\d+' | head -9

Trilinos1/
Trilinos2/
...
```

...
...
ls output.. so on

then typed key output is gone unless palpating typing reset

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a cross-post [from Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/745362/108618). Either the original author cross-posted, [which is wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310), or somebody else "stole" the question.